# Can someone help me interpret these memory leak messages from MAT?

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I'm particularly stumped by Problem Suspect 1 as I can't drill into it to find any more useful information.   The app that I'm building in android studio eventually crashes as you go from activity to activity.

Here's the image.

[image]